# C#: Why is one of my .Where() conditions missing in my SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a method with the following line of code being run. It's supposed to get all the messages that have been created within the past 24 hours and aren't created in a future time (because that shouldn't be possible).

```
messages.AddRange(_dbcontext.Messages
                .Where(message => message.CreationTime >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-24) && message.CreationTime <= DateTime.UtcNow)
                .ToList());
```

When the application runs and passes the above line, this is the SQL Query that ran:

```
SELECT [message].[Id], [message].[CreationTime], [message].[Value]
FROM [Messages] AS [message]
WHERE([message].[CreationTime] <= GETUTCDATE())
```

This basically retrieves all messages, instead of those created within the last 24 hours.

I want to know why this part of the Where() is being ignored or not being transformed to an SQL query, and what I can do to make it work.

```
(message => message.CreationTime >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-24)
```

Comment: i think both query results the same data as both giving you last 24 hours record. I am not sure might Entity framework optimization does this.

Comment: @AmitSingh How would that SQL query only return the last 24 hours of records?

Comment: Try to declare a variable with this date assigned `DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-24)` and use this variable in your entity query. AFAIK entity is unable to translate this directly

Comment: @Misery That's my thought as well, but the question then becomes why entity framework (this is entity framework, isn't it? @SimonP?) complains about this, as it does with other things it cannot convert.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen if the date stored in column is in utc format.

Comment: @AmitSingh Yes, and? The only limit the SQL contains is that it has to be created in the past, not that it has to be at most 24 hours old.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I don't know why it does, but usually it does not succeed to translate it in SQL query and raise an exception (in vb.net it does anyway)

Comment: Added entity framework tag. It's indeed EF, @LasseV.Karlsen.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It sounds like OP is using EF Core, which performs many things which it cannot translate at client side. And why it cannot translate it - I guess it can, just isn't implemented yet. I've noticed this for many `DateTime` methods (basicaly all `AddXyz`) and operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a problem with SQL query translation in EF Core versions prior 2.0 (unsupported `DateTime` methods like `AddHours`, `AddDays` etc.) which leads to so called [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval). Your query should produce correct results, but will be inefficient because the second part of the `where` filter will be evaluated in memory after retrieving all records that match the other condition.

It has been improved in [EF Core 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-0/) where the generated SQL looks like this (as expected):

```
SELECT [message].[Id], [message].[CreationTime], [message].[Value]
FROM [Messages] AS [message]
WHERE ([message].[CreationTime] >= DATEADD(hour, -24E0, GETUTCDATE())) AND ([message].[CreationTime] <= GETUTCDATE())
```

So either upgrade to EF Core 2.0, or use the usual EF workaround by putting the `DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-24)` into variable outside the query and use it inside.

Answer (score 2):

Due to EF incapacity to translate `DateTime` manipulations into a proper SQL query, I suggest the following :

```
DateTime dayBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-24);
messages.AddRange(_dbcontext.Messages
                  .Where(message => message.CreationTime >= dayBefore && message.CreationTime <= DateTime.UtcNow)
                  .ToList());
```

I found this solution using [EF date and time canonical functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/date-and-time-canonical-functions) that apparently work, but I haven't tested it :

```
messages.AddRange(_dbcontext.Messages
            .Where(message => message.CreationTime >= EntityFunctions.AddHours(DateTime.UtcNow, -24) && message.CreationTime <= DateTime.UtcNow)
            .ToList());
```

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT**

`EntityFunctions` is obsolete and has been replaced by [DbFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx) which gives the following example.

```
messages.AddRange(_dbcontext.Messages
            .Where(message => message.CreationTime >= DbFunctions.AddHours(DateTime.UtcNow, -24) && message.CreationTime <= DateTime.UtcNow)
            .ToList());
```